# How can we make topic related to any custom object empty in salesforce

Tags: custom-object

How can we make topic related to any custom object empty in salesforce.I have some for 141 records of a custom object for which I need to remove all topics.

Answer (score 0):

TopicAssignment is the junction object between Topics and your custom objects .

1.Collect all the record Ids for which you need to delete Topics in a CSV .

2.Query the TopicAssignment object and collect in a CSV

Filter file generated in step 2 based only on the file 1 based on the EntityId .

3.Delete the Topic Assignment for only those records .

Alternately you can script an apex as well to query for all the TopicAssigments where EntityId is equal to custom object record Id and delete it .